# Check if a Cognito email exists using cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminGetUser(userPool, email)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

The question "how to determine if a user already exists in Cognito" has been asked and answered in several forums.

However, none have suggested to use `cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminGetUser(params)`.

According to the AWS doco

```
var params = {
  UserPoolId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Username: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
```

and

```
Username — (String)
The user name of the user you want to retrieve.
```

If, in Cognito, you use a `uuid` as username and configure`email` as an alias (ie login using email) then  `cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminGetUser(params)` works perfectly passing either a `uuid` or `email` as the Username parameter.

Is this behaviour documented?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer as an alternative and easy way to test if Cognito contains a supplied email address if users are logging in by email - ie email is an alias of username. My original question was, Is it documented that a username can be either a UUID or an email? This is still unanswered.

```js
const params = {
  UserPoolId: 'userpool uuid',
  Username: 'email' 
};

try {
   let result = await cognitoIdentityServiceProvider
      .adminGetUser(params).promise();
   return result
} catch (error) {
    if (error.code === "UserNotFoundException") {
      return "not found";
    } else {
      return "error";
    }
}
```